# How does yum dependency resolution work?

Tags: yum, rpm, dependencies

If multiple packages satisfy a dependency for a package being installed, how does yum choose which one to automatically install? Can I force it to let me pick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my explorations over this past weekend, it appears that yum will pick the most recent version that satisfies the requirement, and then proceed.

And yes - if you want to pick, you should install it manually (or use `yum install package.ver.si.on`)

Answer (score 2):

Don't know on the first question, but for the second one: You could just install the package of your choice first, so yum doesn't have to install anything anymore to satisfy the particular dependency.